# How can I convert this tensor to a numpy array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'd like to apply the pagerank algorithm to the x_attn tensor. But the nx.pagerank module only accepts numpy arrays. When I try to convert it to using **x_att.eval()**, it says:

"tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'main_input_5' with dtype float and shape [?,6600]".

Can somebody please help me out?

```
def variable_attn_15jan():


    input_dim=input_dim_func()

    main_input = Input(shape=(input_dim,),name='main_input')

    inputs_w1=Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0:3300])(main_input)  
    inputs_w2=Lambda(lambda x: x[:,3300:6600])(main_input) 


    x1_attn= Dense(11, activation='softmax')(inputs_w1)
    x2_attn= Dense(11, activation='softmax')(inputs_w2)


    list_x_att1=[]
    list_x_att2=[]

    for i in range(11) :
        val_scalar=Lambda(lambda x: x[:,i:(i+1)])(x1_attn)
        list_x_att1.append(Lambda(lambda x: x[:,(i*300):(i+1)*300]*val_scalar)(inputs_w1))
    x_att1 = concatenate(list_x_att1)

    for i in range(11) :
        val_scalar=Lambda(lambda x: x[:,i:(i+1)])(x2_attn)
        list_x_att2.append(Lambda(lambda x: x[:,(i*300):(i+1)*300]*val_scalar)(inputs_w2))
    x_att2 = concatenate(list_x_att2)

    x_att = concatenate([x_att1,x_att2])
```

Answer (score 0):

On your tensor (v2.0):

`npa = tf.numpy()`

where npa will be your numpy array name.

Alternatively, tensor (< v2.0):

```py
npa=tf.eval()
print(type(npa))
```

Update 1:

Use below code how to check what type of arrays you've got. Look also at comment from  *rkern* commented posted [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14000) on Jul 14, 2019 .

```py
type(tf)

type(np.array(tf))
```

Comment: What version of tensor? Also..look what you're feeding via `x_attn` as `tf` to .numpy().

Comment: 1.14 (That's the version I need to use.) 
This is the error I get. AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: .numpy() is for version 2.0. Then in your case look at the array shapes before transforming.

Comment: Do you know how I can do it for 1.14?

Comment: try `print(type(tf.Session().run(tf.constant([1,2,3]))))` to see if its a numpy.

Comment: Still the same error. 
_InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'main_input_9' with dtype float and shape [?,6600]_

Comment: can you snippet post in your question a piece of the tf you use as input? Have you checked what you're feeding the Nx. before you run its codeline? It might be you are pasting lets say tf[0] and it should be tf[1]...